# Display text under image - SharePoint 2013 Foundation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, deployment, item-styles

I need help in how to display the text under an image in SharePoint 2013 Foundation. I attached an image to show what the OOTB Picture Library does and what I would like for it to be:

## Currently

[image]

## Goal

[image]

I want to keep the OOTB Picture Library defult view however, would like to have text (specificity the name under the image. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with the promoted links webpart and the tile view myself, but don't have example code here with me. What you will have to do may very well be possible by css (actually, try that first!) but from experience I know the tile view is very very rigid.

What you want to do is just move the text with CSS. Use some developer toolbar to see the output's divs etc and work with that. But it may be that you need some advanced changes through JS.

For example, the text is not actually just text, I believe, it's some sort of box that moves up when you hover (unless it doesn't work the same as it does on promoted links ?) For some seriously stupid reason, the JS that does this hover effect, it puts the description right back into it's original place... I believe in the end I fixed it with css on the bounding box, but you may need JS in your case, don't know. You might choose to delete the box and move the text in a seperate div under the image with JS.

If you do need JS:

One very good solution (imo) is using the new JSLink option! Look it up, it's nice!

This would allow you to run javascript that has *some* sense of the WebPart context, ie, no more quering the page for *a* webpart with a certain class and id. You will just get the webpart handed to you before it's rendered on the page, nice!

Comment: Yeah, it does work the same as the promoted links. For the bounding box, I just used css to make the alpha value zero. I don't know much (if not, any) javascript. I googled the JSLink currently going through it though.

Comment: I'll look up my previous work with it and see if I can post some helpful example code, as what I did was just to make the tiles bigger, so you'll find some similar things in it at least :).

Comment: Great! Thank you. I created a test view based off the Thumbnail.aspx (for testing purposes and not ruin the file) and currently looking to see how the images are placed in a <ul> but cant make sense of the code I'm seeing...its only 45 lines long *shocked*